# How to create 2 columns using the batch filter in twig

Tags: html, twig, craftcms

Im trying to put Pictures into a gallery using the batch filter with twig. I want there to be 2 columns next to eachother, but the code seems not to create the second column. Everything goes into a single column.

```
{% extends "_bildlayout" %}
{% block content %}
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('bilder').limit(16)|batch(8) %}
    <div class="column">
    {% for value in entry %}
        {% set bild = value.bild.one() %}
        <img src="{{ bild.url }}" alt="{{ value.title }}">
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %} 
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Do you have more than 8 items? :)

Comment: yep, 16 actually :)

Comment: Should work as expected then, see [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/woryst)

Comment: yep works now… might have been a typo or sth. thx